# Enter a string interactively on specific keyboard shortcut

Tags: key-bindings, interactive

I'm new to this kind of Q&A site. Now I'm writing some article using *Sphinx* (reStructured text). Writing an equation (like `E = mc^{2}`) in Sphinx is a little bit demanding, because you have to decorate it as follows.

```
:math:`E=mc^{2}`
```

So I wrote a function like the following.

```
(add-hook 'rst-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-m") '(lambda (eq)
                                         (interactive "sEnter LaTeX Equation.")
                                         (insert (concat " :math:`" eq "` "))))))
```

It works

1. `C-m`
2. You are prompted to enter an equation like `E = mc^{2}`
3. Then `` :math:`E=mc^{2}` `` is automatically inserted.

However, very strangely, when I feed `Enter key`, I am again prompted to `Enter LaTeX Equation`, which is not a desired (just entering `Enter` key!!!). How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that you're using Emacs inside of a terminal emulator. Because of how computers evolved from teletype machines, the enter key in a terminal emulator sends exactly the same character as `C-m`; Emacs literally cannot distinguish between them. `C-i` is the same as the tab key, `C-l` is the form-feed character, etc.

Personally, I recommend that you use Emacs as a GUI program (even though it mostly only renders text). GUI programs have much more direct access to the precise details of how keyboards work, and a much better selection of fonts and colors.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> as key sequence instead of <kbd>C-m</kbd>.

The key bindings <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>letter</kbd> just work and are reserved for users.

They are not (should not be) used in any official libraries.

See the [Key Binding Conventions Section in the Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html).

[Db48x](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/9982/db48x) already described the possible reason for your specific problems [in his answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48197/2370).

Comment: Thank you, Tobias and db48x! it worked fine well! Actually, it was the first time to write my own lisp code.